# Register new Server Name in Sql Managment Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008

i want to know is there anyway to register new server in SqlServer Managment Studio??Except the General way in Managment Studio

my Master said there is a Way but i forgot to ask him??(i know we can register new server name in Sql Managment studio by Right click on Current ServerName and click Register but some body say its not a good way to register)

Now i have a server name with windows authentication Security,is there anyway to create a Server Name with user pass(without uninstalling Sql Server)

Answer (score 1):

Press  `CTRL + ALT + G`, this will show the registered servers window, now add a new server group, then add it there or just add the server under the main folder. You do this by right clicking on the group and selecting `New Server Registration`

Comment: i added now server group as you said,i dont understand "add it there" in your answer,can u explain??thanks

Comment: You do this by right clicking on the group and selecting `New Server Registration`

Comment: i did but its name didnt add in server name list to connect to it