# Creating a New Registered SQL Server with Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a new SQL Server that I can add a database to.

I used the following resources, but they didn't work:

**Resources:**

1. [Register new Server Name in Sql Managment Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335175/register-new-server-name-in-sql-managment-studio)
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188231.aspx

Steps I have taken:

1. Opened `Registered Servers`

   [image]
2. Right clicked on `Local Server Groups` and select `New Server Group`

   [image]
3. Here, I add a `Group Name`

   [image]
4. Next, I right clicked on `PlanningCenter` and selected `New Server Registration`

   [image]
5. I name my server and select `Test`, but I get the following error:

   [image]

**Question:**

How can I create a new registered server, am I on the right track?

Comment: Looks like close.  For the "Server name", you need to enter the actual host name (followed by instance name if applicable).  The "Registered server name" can be different as that's just the name that shows in the tree.  I assume the remote server has been configured to allow remote connections as indicted in the error message.

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks for your reply. What do you mean by `host name`? Is this something separate that I need to purchase?

Comment: No, by host name, I mean the network name of the remote computer (that you can PING).  The registered server name is just a mnemonic name that may be different if you choose.

Comment: I hope this isn't an insultingly obvious question.  Have you already created the SQL server, and you are just trying to register it, or has the server not yet been created?

Comment: @BradD, the SQL server has not yet been created.

Comment: I want to create and register one

Comment: @CodeChaser, the registration tool registers connections for existing servers; it doesn't create new SQL Server instances.  You need to run SQL Server setup for that on the server, selecting the create new instance option.

Comment: You can't "create" a new SQL Server from here - if you want to "create" a new SQL Server (a new **instance**) - then you must run the **installation** from your DVD or ISO image. You can only add **existing servers** (and instances) here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a misunderstanding of the functionality

Comment: Thanks for the advice @marc_s. Sounds like I'll have to run my ISO image again to create a new server.